# Have database considerations changed in 4.2

Tags: frameworks, atk4

There where some database considerations in previouse documentation of agiletoolkit, that I can't find anymore.
Have those changed?
For example are booleans still needed to be enum('Y','N')??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 4.2 you can choose the boolean "style", so if you have an old project that uses 'Y','N' enums you could simply fix the definition in the field declaration by chaining `->enum(array('Y','N'))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. What I want is to start a new application, and I don't know how to set up teh new database, is real boolean possible now? or should I still keep with the Y/N?

Comment: The real boolean is possible now, the dsql translate the tru/false value in the appropriate representation in the db. If you want to enumerate the boolean with two strings you can use the syntax exposed above. Check here http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/modeltable/fields